# Proof of the Principle of Double Induction

Tags: logic, induction

I'm working through the exercises in Hrabaceck and Jeck's introductory book on set theory and I'm having some trouble with the proof of the double induction principle. The result is stated as follows: if given fixed $n,m$

$(\forall k)(\forall l)((k<m\vee(k=m\wedge l<n))\Rightarrow P(k,l))\Rightarrow P(m,n)$ (*)

holds, then $P(n,m)$ holds for all $n,m$.

My idea is to try and show that the property $Q(m)=(\forall l)P(m,l)$ holds for all values of $m$, so I assume

$(\forall k)(k<m\Rightarrow(\forall l)P(k,l))$ ($(\forall k)(k<m\Rightarrow Q(k))$)

in an attempt to show that this (together with (*)) implies $Q(m)$  and then use strong induction to conclude the proof.

I'm really not sure where to go from here. Or rather, I seem to get to the answer I'm looking for but I only use strong induction once, which is odd, and makes me think I'm doing something wrong, but I can't find the mistake. I've seen another post with a very similar question about the exact same exercise, but it don't find the answers in there very helpful.

Comment: Are you familiar with the principle of trans transfinite induction? This is just that on the lexicographic ordering on $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I'm familiar with it, but I'd rather not use it, because I'm trying to use only the tools developed up to that point in the book. I've come up with an argument that makes sense to me, because it's entirely based on the axioms of first order logic but it doesn't quite add up.

Comment: @ModestoRosado Below you can find a pedantically detailed answer which describes the precise deduction that I understand you are seeking. I don't know if you have taken a look at it (it appears that it did receive a downvote, and I can only hope it wasn't you...), so I thought of letting you know.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ It wasn't me who downvoted you. I just woke up so I hadn't seen your answer. In fact, I don't see any downvotes in your comment, nor why you should have any. Either way I've taken a quick look at it and it seems to be what I'm looking for (I think I more or less had the same line of reasoning in mind, only that it wasn't nearly as detailed). I'll give it a more careful look later. You didn't need to go that far, but I really appreciate the effort. Also, thank you for sticking with my original strategy. It makes things easier to understand.

Comment: @Modesto Rosado (A first reply) I am glad you found the answer useful and also glad to see you advocate the worthiness of the answer, so to speak. Indeed, the downvote was removed at some later point after I wrote to you yesterday (I myself didn't notice when, exactly). My intention was to produce a sample of "how methodical deduction should rigorously be carried out", bearing in mind that perhaps not too many textbooks on the topic actually take the time to illustrate this by at least one noteworthy example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try to walk through the proof methodically. I will write $\mathscr{Ens}$ to succinctly denote the collection of axioms&schemata of Set Theory. Given the hypothesis:
$$R\colon \equiv(\forall m)(\forall n)(m, n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow [(\forall k)(\forall l)((k<m \wedge l \in \mathbb{N})\vee (k=m \wedge l<n) \Rightarrow P(k, l)) \Rightarrow P(m, n)]),$$
we shall establish that:
$$\mathscr{Ens}, R \vdash (\forall m)(\forall n)(m, n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow P(m, n)). \tag{0}$$
However, we have in $\mathscr{Ens}$ (actually it suffices to consider only the purely logical part, disregarding the axioms which concern sets) the equivalence:
$$(\forall m)(\forall n)(m, n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow P(m, n)) \Leftrightarrow (\forall m)(m \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow (\forall n)(n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow P(m, n))),$$
so in order to prove (0) it will suffice to establish that:
$$\mathscr{Ens}, R \vdash (\forall m)(m \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow Q(m)), \tag{1}$$
where as you quite appropriately indicated we introduce:
$$Q(m)\colon \equiv (\forall n)(n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow P(m, n)).$$
By virtue of the principle of induction in its so-called "strong" form, in order to establish (1) it suffices to prove that:
$$\mathscr{Ens}, R \vdash (\forall m)(m \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow ((\forall k)(k<m \Rightarrow Q(k))\Rightarrow Q(m))). \tag{1'}$$

Since neither $\mathscr{Ens}$ nor $R$ contain any letters (variables) -- in other words, the theory whose list of axioms&schemata is given by $\mathscr{Ens}$ together with $R$ has no *constants* -- it suffices to establish the dequantified version of (1'):
$$\mathscr{Ens}, R \vdash m \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow ((\forall k)(k<m \Rightarrow Q(k))\Rightarrow Q(m)), \tag{1''}$$
since requantification is possible (over letters which are not constants). Appealing to the *Metatheorem of Deduction*, in order to prove (1'') it will suffice to establish:
$$\mathscr{Ens}, R, m \in \mathbb{N} \vdash (\forall k)(k<m \Rightarrow Q(k))\Rightarrow Q(m), \tag{1'''}$$
and by once again applying this metatheorem to reduce to:
$$\mathscr{Ens}, R, m \in \mathbb{N}, (\forall k)(k<m \Rightarrow Q(k)) \vdash Q(m). \tag{1''''}$$

Resorting once again to the strong form of the induction principle, in order to prove (1'''') it will suffice to show that:
$$\mathscr{Ens}, R, m \in \mathbb{N}, (\forall k)(k<m \Rightarrow Q(k)) \vdash (\forall n)(n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow [(\forall l)(l<n \Rightarrow P(m, l)) \Rightarrow P(m, n)]). \tag{2}$$
Since the letter $n$ is not found amongst the constants of the theory described by the collection of $\mathscr{Ens}, R, m \in \mathbb{N}, (\forall k)(k<m \Rightarrow Q(k))$ -- whose only constant is $m$, a distinct letter -- in order to prove (2) establishing the dequantified version:
$$\mathscr{Ens}, R, m \in \mathbb{N}, (\forall k)(k<m \Rightarrow Q(k)) \vdash n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow [(\forall l)(l<n \Rightarrow P(m, l)) \Rightarrow P(m, n)] \tag{2'}$$
will suffice, by the same token mentioned above of dequantification/requantification over non-constants. Similarly, by once again appealing to the metatheorem of deduction, proving (2') will be achieved as long as we establish that:
$$\mathscr{Ens}, R, m, n \in \mathbb{N}, (\forall k)(k<m \Rightarrow Q(k)) \vdash (\forall l)(l<n \Rightarrow P(m, l)) \Rightarrow P(m, n), \tag{2''}$$
and a further application of the metatheorem of deduction reduces our task to that of establishing:
$$\mathscr{Ens}, R, m, n \in \mathbb{N}, (\forall k)(k<m \Rightarrow Q(k)), (\forall l)(l<n \Rightarrow P(m, l)) \vdash P(m, n). \tag{2'''}$$

For simplicity, let $\mathscr{T}$ denote the theory whose list of axioms&schemata is given by the collection $\mathscr{Ens}, R, m, n \in \mathbb{N}, (\forall k)(k<m \Rightarrow Q(k)), (\forall l)(l<n \Rightarrow P(m, l))$. Since $R$ is obviously deducible from $\mathscr{T}$, we can also deduce the dequantified version:
$$\mathscr{T} \vdash m, n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow [(\forall k)(\forall l)((k<m \wedge l \in \mathbb{N})\vee (k=m \wedge l<n) \Rightarrow P(k, l)) \Rightarrow P(m, n)]. \tag{3}$$
Since furthermore $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ is also deducible from $\mathscr{T}$ we gather by applying *modus ponens* to (3) that:
$$\mathscr{T} \vdash (\forall k)(\forall l)((k<m \wedge l \in \mathbb{N}) \vee (k=m \wedge l<n) \Rightarrow P(k, l)) \Rightarrow P(m, n). \tag{4}$$
In order to prove that $\mathscr{T} \vdash P(m, n)$, it will suffice by virtue of the modus ponens method of deduction to establish that the antecedent of the implication at (4) is also deducible from $\mathscr{T}$, in other words that: $$\mathscr{T} \vdash (\forall k)(\forall l)((k<m \wedge l \in \mathbb{N}) \vee (k=m \wedge l<n) \Rightarrow P(k, l)). \tag{5}$$
Since the only constants of $\mathscr{T}$ are $m$ and $n$ -- which are distinct from $k$ and $l$ -- in order to prove (5) it will suffice to prove the dequantified version:
$\mathscr{T} \vdash (k<m \wedge l \in \mathbb{N}) \vee (k=m \wedge l<n) \Rightarrow P(k, l), \tag{5'}$
by the same token of dequantification/requantification that we have already mentioned a number of times. In its own turn, relation (5') can be deduced by virtue of the *method of disjunction of cases* as long as we separately establish that:
$$\mathscr{T} \vdash (k<m \wedge l \in \mathbb{N}) \Rightarrow P(k, l) \tag{6a}$$
respectively:
$$\mathscr{T} \vdash (k=m \wedge l<n) \Rightarrow P(k, l). \tag{6b}$$
By virtue of the metatheorem of deduction, relations (6a) and (6b) can be reformulated as:
$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{T}, k<m \wedge l \in \mathbb{N} &\vdash P(k, l) \tag{6a'}\\
\mathscr{T}, k=m \wedge l<n &\vdash P(k, l). \tag{6b'}
\end{align}$$
We clearly have:
$$\mathscr{T} \vdash (\forall k)(k<m \Rightarrow Q(k)), \tag{7}$$
whence by dequantification we infer in particular that:
$$\mathscr{T} \vdash k<m \Rightarrow Q(k). \tag{7'}$$
Since any theorem of a weaker theory remains a theorem for any stronger theory, it is clear that:
$$\mathscr{T}, k<m \wedge l \in \mathbb{N} \vdash k<m \Rightarrow Q(k). \tag{7''}$$
It is also obvious that:
$$\mathscr{T}, k<m \wedge l \in \mathbb{N} \vdash k<m, l \in \mathbb{N} \tag{7'''}$$ -- as a conjunction always implies any of its terms --
whence by modus ponens in combination with (7'') we obtain:
$$\mathscr{T}, k<m \wedge l \in \mathbb{N} \vdash Q(k),$$
which written out explicitly is precisely:
$$\mathscr{T}, k<m \wedge l \in \mathbb{N} \vdash (\forall n)(n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow P(k, n)). \tag{8}$$
Particularising $n$ as $l$ we further obtain:
$$\mathscr{T}, k<m \wedge l \in \mathbb{N} \vdash l \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow P(k, l), \tag{8'}$$
and modus ponens in combination with (7’’’) yields precisely (6a’).
As to (6b’),  we first note that by definition:
$$\mathscr{T} \vdash (\forall l)(l<n \Rightarrow P(m, l)),$$
whence by dequantification we have:
$$\mathscr{T} \vdash l<n \Rightarrow P(m, l) \tag{9}.$$
The same implication is also deducible from the stronger theory:
$$\mathscr{T}, k=m \wedge l<n \vdash l<n \Rightarrow P(m, l), \tag{9’}$$
and we remark that by a token similar to that explained in the case of relation (7’’’) we have in this instance:
$$\mathscr{T}, k=m \wedge l<n \vdash k=m, l<n. \tag{7’’’’}$$
Applying modus ponens to (7’’’’) and (9’) we gather:
$$\mathscr{T}, k=m \wedge l<n \vdash P(m, l). \tag{9’’}$$
By virtue of one of the schemata which axiomatise the relation of equality, we have in particular:
$$\mathscr{T}, k=m \wedge l<n \vdash k=m \Rightarrow (P(k, l) \Leftrightarrow P(m, l)),$$
whence by modus ponens in combination with (7’’’’) it follows that:
$$\mathscr{T}, k=m \wedge l<n \vdash P(k, l) \Leftrightarrow P(m, l),$$
which furthermore entails:
$$\mathscr{T}, k=m \wedge l<n \vdash P(m, l) \Rightarrow P(k, l). \tag{9’’’}$$
A final application of modus ponens between (9'') and (9’’’) establishes (6b’) and concludes our argument.

Comment: I read your answer really carefully and I must say I'm impressed with the amount of detail. I think I understood most of it, although there are some details that elude me, but that's only because I haven't had a lot of practice with first order logic.

Comment: @Modesto Rosado (A second reply) Feel free to ask if you want further clarification, truth is I didn't shy away from referring to some technicalities which are after all omnipresent in mathematical deduction. How one treats these technicalities intimately depends on the formal language adopted to express mathematics, and I have the pretension that I adhere to one such language that wonderfully combines rigour with efficiency (it is the language developed by Bourbaki in their "Théorie des Ensembles").

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that for any fixed $m$, $n$ you have
$$(\forall k)(\forall l)((k<m\vee(k=m\wedge l<n))\Rightarrow P(k,l))\Rightarrow P(m,n).$$
Now assume that $P(M,N)$ is false for some $(M,N)$, and take $(M,N)$ to be (among the values for which $P$ is false) the one for which, for every $M^{\prime}$, $N^{\prime}$ such that $P(M^{\prime},N^{\prime})$ is false, either $M < M^{\prime}$ or $M = M^{\prime}$ and $N \leq N^{\prime}$ (i.e. the lexicographically first such pair).

Now you can get an easy contradiction (assuming that $P(1,1)$ is true).

*An alternate method if you don't like contradiction, assume $P(1,1)$ and then show that $P(m,1)$ is true for all $m$. Then for each $m$, use $P(m,1)$ to show that $P(m,n)$ is true for all $n$. This seems to be like your attempted proof, you do need to use induction twice here because you need to show that if the statement is true for $m=1$, then it is true for all $m$.*